# Get value from SQLite and Cursor comparison problem

Tags: java, android

I access the SQLite database on device. And get some values from table

```
Cursor c = db.query(.....);
```

I try compare this values to other string values like that:

```
if(c.getString(0) == "value")
```

but this comparison returns false all time.

In debug, i see the values and `c.getString(0)` is "value", but comparison returns false..

How can I compare these values?

I tried `c.getString(0).toString()` too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
if(c.getString(0).equals("value"))
```

Answer (score 0):

realize that `c.getString(0)` means that you are requesting the 0 column index on the record currently being pointed to by the Cursor object.  if you are not using managedQuery, i suggest you call `c.moveToFirst()` before attempting to pull data.  then explicity request the column index you want with `c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("nameofcolumn"));`.  note, of course, that "nameofcolumn" must have been requested in the query.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `toString()` after getting value like `getString(0)`. You can just simply compare this using this statement:

```
if(cursor.getString(0).equals("value")){

}
```